# How To Define ListView Scrolled In Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

In Android API-8 if ListView Scrolling We Use :

```
listview.setaOnScrollListener()
```

when Items Are More Then Screen , ListView ScrollBar Shows InBehind , But If Items Are Few So ListView Scrollbar Will Hide;
So if i want to know Items in ListView Are More Than Show In Screen Or Not,  And ListView Is Scrolled . How To Reach I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount` gives you the last item shown on screen, so using this you should know if you are seeing all of them. To do this you have to extend `ListView`

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int     totalItemCount) {
    if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
         //all your items are visible
    }
}
```